# Stop body scroll on button click

Tags: jquery, scroll

So this is my page: http://mediaslave.ca/

What I need is a way of controlling the body scroll. WHen I go to portfolio I have a couple of buttons that pop up a div with the portfolio content. What I'd like is for the body to be unable to scroll when those portfolio divs are up.

Anybody got some advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: call $.plax.disable() when portfolia divs are up and then call enable whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow: hidden` css rule to the `body` element. Also you have to prevent your javascript scroll listeners.

Comment: Hmm. Not exactly sure how to do that, if Im honest. This is the script I am using to make the portfolio divs appear. Is there a way to tack on something that will stop the body from scrolling while these are open?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button.portlink").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio-1").fadeIn("3000");
 $("#portfolio-2").fadeOut("2000");
 $("#portfolio-3").fadeOut("2000");
 $("#portfolio-4").fadeOut("2000");
 $("#portfolio-5").fadeOut("2000");
  });
});